# Invariant Violation : scrollToIndex out of range : requested NaN but maximum is 1 (FlatLList/SwiperFlatList)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

When I want to distribute my data from my firebase database to my React Native mobile application in the form of a carousel with SwiperFlatList, an error is displayed
each time my class is updated, showing me as follows: "Invariant violation: scrolltoindex out of range: requested Nan but maximum is 1."
By hiding the error the carousel works well but it can be very annoying and cause problems during its build.

Here are my codes:

My Render function :

```js
renderPost=post=>{
   
        return(
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <HorizontalCard title={post.title_new} desc={post.text} img={post.image} />
        </View>
        )
      
      }
```

HorizontalCard Component :

```js
export default class HorizontalCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    screen: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    desc: PropTypes.string,
    img: PropTypes.string,
  };

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  };

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }
  render() {
     return (
       <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        this.setModalVisible(true);
      }}
      style={styles.container}>
      <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      visible={this.state.modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        alert('Modal has been closed.');
      }}>
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <View>
          <Text>{this.props.desc}</Text>

          <Button
          title="Fermer la fenêtre"
            onPress={() => {
              this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
            }} />

        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
      <View style={styles.card_discord}>
        <Image style={styles.card_discord_img} source={{ uri: this.props.img }} />
        <LinearGradient
          start={[1.0, 0.5]}
          end={[0.0, 0.5]}
          colors={['rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2)', '#333333', '#333333']}
          style={styles.FadeAway}>
          <View style={styles.FadeAway}>
            <Text h4 style={styles.FadeAway_h2}>
              {this.props.title}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.FadeAway_p}>{this.props.desc}</Text>
          </View>
        </LinearGradient>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
        
  );
  }
 
}
```

My HomeScreen component (page where the error appears) :

```js
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref =  Fire.shared.firestore.collection('posts')
        this.useref=
        this.state={
            dataSource : [],
        }
    }

      feedPosts = (postSnapShot) =>{
        const post = [];
        postSnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
        const {uid,text,timestamp,title_new,image} = doc.data();
        const data=Fire.shared.firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then(doc=>{
          post.push({ 
            text,
            timestamp,
            title_new,
            image,
            uid,
          })
          this.setState({
            dataSource : post,
          });
        }) 
        });
      }

      renderPost=post=>{
   
        return(
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <HorizontalCard title={post.title_new} desc={post.text} img={post.image} />
        </View>
        )
      
      } 
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider>
                <ScrollView>
                             <SwiperFlatList
                                autoplay
                                autoplayDelay={5}
                                index={0}
                                autoplayLoop
                                autoplayInvertDirection
                                data={this.state.dataSource}
                                renderItem={({item})=>this.renderPost(item)}         
                            />
                          ...
                <ScrollView>
            </ThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
```